# How to detect emoji as unicode in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, emoji

i have text file that contain emoji unicode caracter for exemple ,  ☹️, , , , , , .

For example the code \N{1F60D} correspond to 
I use recommendation as in https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html section Creating Unicode.
My program must detect them and do some treatments, but if i use

```
open(FIC1, ">$fic");

while (<FIC>) {
my $ligne=$_;

if( $ligne=~/\N{1F60D}/  )
{print "heart ";
    }
}
```

Now I do this, it work

```
open(FIC1, ">$fic");

while (<FIC>) {
my $ligne=$_;

if( $ligne=~//  )
{print "Heart ";
    }
}
```

What is the problem with the first code
 Regards

Comment: which version of perl are you using? `perl -v` and which platform?

Comment: @Flying_whale: I did all what you recommended , but nothing changed.

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul : This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Comment: see my answer add `-C` option

Comment: note that `U+` is missing betwen `\N{` .. `}`

Comment: How did you open the `FIC` file handle? Did you use an I/O layer to decode the input from octets to Unicode? If so did you use the correct encoding? Please show the output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $ligne;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for `\N`, you see that it means "named Unicode character or character sequence".

You can use this instead:

```
if ($ligne =~ m/\N{U+1F60D}/)
# or
if ($ligne =~ m/\x{1F60D}/)
```

Edit: It's also described in the link you posted,
 https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html

Edit:
The content you read is probably not decoded. You want:

```
use Encode;
...
my $ligne = decode_utf8 $_;
```

or simply open the file directly in utf8 mode:

```
open my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename or die "Could not open $filename: $!";
while (my $ligne = <$fh>) {
    if ($ligne =~ m/\N{U+1F60D}/) { ... }
}
```

You never showed how you open the filehandle called `FIC`, so I assumed it was utf8 decoded.
Here is another good tutorial about unicode in perl: https://perlgeek.de/en/article/encodings-and-unicode

Comment: sorry but this also don't work, it is the same thing, you only added m. also i tested with \x and don't work.

Comment: I did not only add m. Take a closer look please. I added `U+`

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue was with the openin of the file, so what solved my problem is that command my $ligne = decode_utf8 $_; , thank you

Answer (score 6):

For detecting emoji, I would use unicode properties in regexes, e.g.:

- `\p{Emoticons}` or
- `\p{Block: Emoticons}`

For example, print out only emoji

```
perl -CSDA -nlE 'say for( /(\p{Emoticons})/g )' <<< 'abcαβγ'
```

will print

For more info see [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html)

Answer (score 2):

use `perl -C` can be used to enable unicode features

```
perl -C -E 'say "\N{U+263a}"'|perl -C -ne 'print if /\N{U+263a}/'
```

[from perl run](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

> -C [number/list]
>
> The -C flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features.
>   ...

The reason why the second code works is that perl matches UTF-8 binary sequence:  as in `perl -ne 'print if /\xf0\x9f\x98\x8d/'`.

Following should work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -C
open(FIC1, ">$fic");

while (<FIC>) {
    my $ligne=$_;

    if( $ligne=~/\N{U+1F60D}/  ) {
        print "heart ";
    }
}
```

Comment: i try perl -C, but nothing happened, it take long time, i think this blocked the terminal, if i add in my program #!/usr/bin/perl -C, but I have the same result, the second command i don't understand how to use it

Comment: the given examples are to test from command line, without -e or -E + command the perl program is waiting for input to read commands, if it doesn't work it may be because of `U+` missing